# Solve equation in Floor and ceiling functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\lfloor |x+1|-|x-1| \rfloor$=$x$

I know what is mean the "Floor and ceiling functions" but I dont understand how to solve this equation.
Thank you !!

Comment: On the inside of the floor function it appears you have absolute value signs.  Your first step should be to try to get rid of those.  Break into cases:  $x+1\geq 0$ and $x-1\geq 0$,  $x+1\geq 0$ and $x-1<0$, and $x+1<0$ and $x-1<0$.  Do any nice cancellations happen in any of those?

Comment: A different first step would be to notice that if $x$ equals a floor, then $x$ is an integer, in which case the _argument_ to the floor function is an integer too -- and the floor doesn't do anything. So you're looking for $x\in\mathbb Z$ that satisfy $x=|x+1|-|x-1|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x-1$ and $x+1$ differ only by $2$. This means that $|x+1|$ and $|x-1|$ differ by no more than $2$. Hence $-2\le[|x+1|-|x-1|]\le2$ and so $-2\le x\le 2$ and $x$ is an integer because $x$ equals to this floor function. Now you can just brute-force all $x$s from $-2$ to $2$ and find which of them satisfy this identity.